# Regex: Preg_replace all special characters except ½

Tags: php, regex

I need to remove all special characters except ½

```
preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string);
```

Here's what I have so far.  Do I Convert ½ to something else?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try pasting the `½` character inside of your match?

Comment: When I add ½ inside the match, it would not replace other special characters  IE §╚┬

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/aLB

Comment: None of these answers worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `½` to the character group, however you will have to switch to unicode (utf-8) mode with the modifier `u`.

```
$string = "Example: ½¼";
var_dump(
  preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9½-]/u', '', $string)
);
```

Output:

```
string(9) "Example½"
```

You can use the provide the character as unicode codepoint, too.

```
var_dump(
  preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\x{00BD}-]/u', '', $string)
);
```

Without the unicode mode it will match the two bytes of the character separately. This can result in partially removed characters.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `½` to the regex and there you go:

```
preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9½\-]/', '', $string);
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 1):

Try the Unicode hexadecimal x00BD formatted `\x{00BD}`:

```
preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\x{00BD}-]/', '', $string);
```

Also, no need to escape the `-` if it's at the beginning or end of the character class.